# I can't get my favicon to change

Tags: html, favicon

I need help with my website's favicon.
The current code I use for my favicon is:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.png" type="image/x-icon"></link>
```

But for some reason it's not working,
does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="myicon.png">`

Answer (score 1):

You say the icon is of the type "icon" (`image/x-icon`). Just change `x-icon` to say `png` instead. The full snippet:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Logo.png" type="image/png"></link>
```